# Android Studio autocomplete on special character (space, period, etc.) like in Visual Studio

Tags: android-studio, autocomplete, editor

Is it possible to enable autocompletion of the selected suggestion when entering special characters like in Visual Studio?

For example:

When typing 'MenuI' Android Studio suggests 'MenuInflater' that I can autocomplete by hitting TAB after which I type SPACE to separate my variable name.

[image: autocompletion]

In Visual Studio I can type SPACE directly (instead of TAB) to get the autocompletion plus my space character. This works for other special characters like period, brackets and so on, too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, I have also faced the same issue in Android studio. And finally I found it here.
Open the Android Studio settings go to Editor --> General --> Code Completion
 and check the option "Insert selected variant by typing dot, space, etc."

And uncheck the options "Basic completion (Ctrl+Space)" and "Smart Type Completion (Ctrl+Shift+Space)"

[Check this Android studio settings image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKJCB.jpg)

Comment: This not working for me I tried every possible solution to stop autocomplete on dot

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is implemented, *slightly.*

If you have `MenuInflater` and type in `MenuI`, and then `CTRL+SPACE`, which means you tell the IDE that you want to use the autocomplete dropdown, and then press space, it works as you wish.

---

So, I could type in `MenuIn`, then I could either press the down key, or use `CTRL+SPACE` (*"MenuInflater" Should now be highlighted in blue:*
[image: What you should see after pressing CTRL+SPACE or downkey]
), and then press space, and it'll work as you wish.

---

I suck at explaining, so if you don't get it, I'll try more.

Comment: Interesting. Unfortunately, as I still need to press CTRL+SPACE it doesn't save me from pressing TAB. But its useful if you use the navigation keys anyway. Insofar it is the solution for about half the cases.

Comment: @xvlcw thanks. I find it stupid that you can't do this in Android Studio.

Comment: Oh btw, I made sure that it is impossible by switching my shortcuts to visual studio's via settings in Android Studio. So sadly, CTRL+SPACE is the only solution.